# Using a sprite sheet and Matrix to draw to Canvas

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, sprite-sheet

In my app I want my sprites to rotate based on the direction they are heading, this is already done nicely with a Matrix.

However, now after trying to implement some sprite animation, I have realised there is not a Canvas.drawBitmap(...) method which takes a Matrix and allows clipping of a sprite sheet.

Is there a way to clip a sprite sheet into seperate Bitmaps before I have to draw them i.e in onCreate of my custom SurfaceView, can I create an array of Bitmaps to contain my sprites by clipping the sheet?

Thanks
Andy

P.S I am aware of rotating the Canvas to achieve rotated images, but seeing as all my code is set up and working nicely I would hate to have to change it

Comment: any luck with this? I have same problem.

Comment: I don't think I found an answer to this in the end. There must be some way to clip the sprite sheet into separate image variables first, I think that is the only solution.

I'm using Corona2D now; http://coronalabs.com/

It was recommended to me by someone in the industry and it is brilliant.

Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: I found a solution to my problem, i just flipped the canvas using scaled -1f, 1f and deduct its width and the width of the image to cope with the offset that the flipping caused. It seemed to worked well for me.